# Are OneDrive preferences stored per PC or per account?

Tags: user-accounts, active-directory, onedrive

In an Azure Active Directory environment, where all accounts are in AD, and we are using Office 365 OneDrive - are the OneDrive preferences stored per PC, or per AD account? *I.e.* if a user logs onto one PC, configures OneDrive prefs, logs out, and then logs into another PC, will those OneDrive settings follow them, or must the user reconfigure OneDrive on the second PC?

Comment: This entirely depends on your AD configuration, typically it would be per machine, even if you are dealing with an AD user.  You could have a rolling AD profile, since I don't have an AD configuration that implement rolling profiles, I can't test it myself.

Comment: @Ramhound do you mean roaming profiles?